# Mojolicious receive post result

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I came from perl Cgi's, and i am starting with mojolicious ( and web frameworks too ), using as example this github:
https://github.com/webdevesgi/mojolicious-demo

I have this template:

```
  % layout 'menu2';
   <hr/>


   % if ( stash 'result' ) { 
      <li><%= stash 'result' %></li>
   % } else  { 
      <li>bar</li>
   % } 
  <ul>
  % foreach my $url (keys %$urls) {
      <li><%= $urls->{$url}->{'url_origin'} %> - <a target="blank" href="http://localhost:3000/l/<%= $urls->{$url}->{'url_short'} %>">!<%= $urls->{$url}->{'url_short'} %></a> (<%= $urls->{$url}->{'clics'} %> clics)</li>
  % }
</ul>
<br/>

<%= form_for sendurl => (method => 'post', class => 'well form-search' target = "_self") => begin %>
    <p>Raccourcir une url :
    <%= text_field 'orig_url', class => 'input-xlarge' %>
    <%= submit_button 'GO', class => 'btn btn-warning' %>
    </p>



<% end %>
```

And i want to view in this template after doing a post, the result of the action, with this lines:

```
% if ( stash 'result' ) { 
          <li><%= stash 'result' %></li>
       % } else  { 
          <li>bar</li>
       % }
```

This is the code for sendurl:

```
sub sendurl{
  my $self = shift;

  my $url =  Mojo::URL->new($self->param('orig_url'));
  if(!$url->is_abs){
      return $self->redirect_to('dashboard');
  }

  my $short_url = encodeurl($self->param('orig_url'));

  $self->urls->addUrl($self->session('user'), $self->param('orig_url'), $short_url);


  my $params = $self->req->params->to_hash;

  if ($params) {
      $self->stash( 'result' , "Errors - not sent" );
      open F, q[>],'log.txt';print F Dumper $self;close F;
  }

  $self->redirect_to('dashboard', result=> "Errors - not sent");

}
```

In the log.txt i can see the stash having the value:

```
 'stash' => {
                          'mojo.session' => {
                                              'user_type' => 'admin',
                                              'user' => 'foo'
                                            },
                          'mojo.captures' => {
                                               'controller' => 'login',
                                               'action' => 'sendurl'
                                             },
                          'menu' => $VAR1->{'app'}{'defaults'}{'config'}{'app_menu'}{'admin'},
                          'urls' => {
                                      '' => {
                                              'url_short' => '!532f1b4f',
                                              'id' => undef,
                                              'url_origin' => 'www.foo.bar/baz',
                                              'clics' => undef
                                            }
                                    },
                          'mojo.active_session' => 2,
                          'mojo.started' => [
                                              1395596194,
                                              529165
                                            ],
                          'controller' => 'login',
                          'mojo.routed' => 1,
                          'action' => 'sendurl',
                          'mojo.secret' => 'login',
                          'config' => $VAR1->{'app'}{'defaults'}{'config'},
                          'result' => 'Errors - not sent'
                        },
```

But in the web explorer i cant see the value of result

How can i achieve this? 
How can i pass a a result from sendurl to the view, and in the view check for a result variable in stash is defined?
This is the best way to work with mojolicious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got time to look more into the problems now. As you have found out, `stash` entries do not survive a `redirect_to`, but you can use `flash` instead.

I've done some minor changes to the code as well to at least get rid of some of the most peculiar things. After those changes, the debug output from `morbo` looks sane.

**lib/Login.pm**

Instead of calling a controller action for checking if a user is logged in, use a simple callback:

```
my $logged_in = $r->under->to(cb => sub {
  my $self = shift;
  return defined $self->session('user');
});
```

**lib/Login/Login.pm**

Renamed the `logged_in` sub to `dashboard` (which fix the *action not found* error), and add a proper `render` call at the end (to render the `login/dashboard` template).

```
sub dashboard {
  my $self = shift;
  $self->stash(
      urls => $self->urls->getUrls($self->session('user')),
  );
  return $self->render;
}
```

In `sub send_url` I changed the `$self->stash(result =>` to `flash`:

```
my $params = $self->req->params->to_hash;
if ($params) {
  $self->flash(result => "Errors - not sent");
}
```

**templates/login/dashboard.html.ep**

Your check for `result` became:

```
<li><%= flash('result') // 'result not in flash' %></li>
```

And some final advices:

- The database access can be improved *a lot*. Use the excellent [Mojolicious::Plugin::Database](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious%3a%3aPlugin%3a%3aDatabase) instead of trying to figure out how to get things working with prefork/hypnotoad.
- **Never, never, never** untar the Mojolicious source code directly into your app! (or checking in the VCS...)
- Use a proper build environment (EU::MM, M::B etc).
- Read the Mojolicious documentation, and begin coding in small scale ([Mojolicious::Lite](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Lite)) and grow it to a full app if neccessary (following the guidelines in [Mojolicious::Guides::Growing](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Growing)).

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

You can access the content of stash directly as `$result`. See for example the documentation at http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Lite#Stash_and_templates.

Reciting the code linked to:

```
use Mojolicious::Lite;

# Route leading to an action that renders a template
get '/bar' => sub {
  my $self = shift;
  $self->stash(one => 23);
  $self->render('baz', two => 24);
};

app->start;
__DATA__

@@ baz.html.ep
The magic numbers are <%= $one %> and <%= $two %>.
```

Running that `app` gives:

```
$ perl app.pl get /bar
[Sun Mar 23 23:20:32 2014] [debug] Your secret passphrase needs to be changed!!!
[Sun Mar 23 23:20:32 2014] [debug] GET "/bar".
[Sun Mar 23 23:20:32 2014] [debug] Routing to a callback.
[Sun Mar 23 23:20:32 2014] [debug] Rendering template "baz.html.ep" from DATA section.
[Sun Mar 23 23:20:32 2014] [debug] 200 OK (0.010140s, 98.619/s).
The magic numbers are 23 and 24.
$
```